# Função para verificar combobox e selecionar um RegExp apropriado

Tags: javascript, regex, combobox

Como eu posso inserir uma função que verifica a `optionlist` e após isso verifica o regexp dos bancos abaixo? São 8 dígitos permitidos no regexp para verificar a conta em cada banco, não sei como fazer essa função.

```js
 function check(){
        var verificaInput = document.querySelector("#agencia").value;
        //Tá okay
        var reg = /^[0-9]{4}$/;
        
        if(reg.exec(verificaInput)){
          //Se for igual a true
          if(reg.test(verificaInput)){
            //Seu código aqui
            console.log("Passou");
          }
        }
        else{
          alert("Digite agência e conta novamente");
        }
        
    }
    
        
    function changebancos(){
        var selectedoption = document.getElementById("optionvalue");
        //A coleção de option do seu select
        var options = selectedoption.options;
        //options.length: pega a quantidade
       for(var i = 0; i < options.length;i++){
          console.log(options[i].value);
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label>
    <select id="optionvalue" function="changebancos()" >

            <option value= "0">Banco do Brasil</option>
            <option value="1">Itaú</option>
            <option value="2">Bradesco</option>
            <option value="3">Santander</option>
            <option value="4">Sorocred</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="number" name="agencia" id="agencia"/>
        <br>
        <input type="number" name="conta" id="conta"/>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="btnCheck"value="click to check" onclick="check(this.id)"/>
    </label>
       
</body>
</html>
```

Esse último `console.log` que coloquei não está retornando nada no console. Eu preciso que ele retorne qual `option` foi selecionada após clicar no botão `btnCheck`, e após isso com uma função verificar qual banco foi selecionado e verificar o RegExp se confere.

Comment: Não ficou clara sua questão, poderia explicá-la melhor?

Comment: Se quer validar exatamente 8 dígitos, use `/^[0-9]{8}$/` - o número entre chaves [indica a quantidade](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit). E se quiser no máximo 8 dígitos, use `/^[0-9]{0,8}$/`. E não precisa chamar `exec` **e** `test`, chame apenas um deles (se só quer saber se é válido, use `test`, se quer extrair informações do *match*, use `exec`) - leia a documentação para saber a diferença: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0):

O último `console.log` não imprime nada porque a função `changebancos` não está sendo chamada.

Se você quer que ela seja chamada toda vez que o `select` for alterado, use `onchange="changebancos()"`, e não `function="changebancos()"` (veja a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange)).

Segue um exemplo (removi as partes do seu HTML que não eram essenciais para mostrar o funcionamento do `onchange` e a validação do `select`). Na função `changebancos` eu só imprimi a opção escolhida com `console.log`, mas você pode alterar para fazer o que precisar com esse valor:

```js
function check() {
    // agência pode ter entre 1 e 4 dígitos
    let regAgencia = /^[0-9]{1,4}$/;
    // conta pode ter entre 4 e 8 dígitos
    let regConta = /^[0-9]{4,8}$/;

    let agencia = document.getElementById("agencia").value;
    let conta = document.getElementById("conta").value;
    if(regAgencia.test(agencia) && regConta.test(conta)){
        console.log("Passou");
    } else {
        alert("Digite agência e conta novamente");
    }
}

function changebancos() {
    let selectBanco = document.getElementById("banco");
    let opcao = selectBanco.options[selectBanco.selectedIndex];
    console.log(`Banco ${opcao.text} selecionado, valor=${opcao.value}`);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <select id="banco" onchange="changebancos()">
        <option value= "0">Banco do Brasil</option>
        <option value="1">Itaú</option>
        <option value="2">Bradesco</option>
        <option value="3">Santander</option>
        <option value="4">Sorocred</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="agencia" id="agencia"/>
    <input type="number" name="conta" id="conta"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnCheck"value="click to check" onclick="check()"/>
</form>
```

Também mudei as regex. Você estava usando `/^[0-9]{4}$/`, que verifica exatamente 4 dígitos. Mas depois você menciona 8 dígitos, e não ficou claro se é exatamente 8 ou no máximo 8.

De qualquer forma, para a agência usei `/^[0-9]{1,4}$/` (o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{1,4}` significa "no mínimo 1 e no máximo 4", ou seja, a agência pode ter entre 1 e 4 dígitos), e para a conta usei `/^[0-9]{4,8}$/` (no mínimo 4 e no máximo 8 dígitos). **São só exemplos, ajuste os valores para o que você precisar** (se quer exatamente 8 dígitos, por exemplo, use `/^[0-9]{8}$/`).

Também usei apenas o método `test`, pois não é necessário chamar `exec` e `test` em sequência (pois assim você está verificando a mesma regex duas vezes desnecessariamente).

O [método `exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) retorna um array contendo várias informações sobre o *match* encontrado. Se você não vai usar essas informações e só quer saber se a string corresponde à regex, basta usar o [método `test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), que retorna `true` ou `false`.